# Build fails because of "lexical or preprocessor issue" relating to bits/os_defines.h

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc

When I try to build, I'm suddenly getting the error

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'bits/os_defines.h' file not found

[image]

What could possibly cause this?

`/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits` looks fine.

Comment: Screenshots aren't searchable.

Comment: There is not enough detail in this question.  What version of Xcode are you using?  Does the project use Objective-C++?  Show the contents of `c++config.h`.

Comment: So your compiler compiles screenshots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-imports sometimes add bad header files. Look for a bad header import.